# Call to a member function delete() on a non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im  trying to delete value form web page 
but get an error

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function delete() on a non-object
```

Here's my controller code:

```
public function delete(){
    $id=Input::get('id');
    $galleries=ForumGallery::find($id);
    $galleries->delete();
    return Redirect ::route('gallery',$id);
}
```

And the according route:

```
Route::get('/Gallery/delete',array('uses'=>'GalleryController@destroy','as'=>'d‌​estroy'))
```

how to solve it?

Comment: Without your code we have no way of knowing what the problem is.

Comment: sorry.....my controller.php code is ..public function delete(){$id=Input::get('id');
     $galleries=ForumGallery::find($id);
     $galleries->delete();
     return Redirect ::route('gallery',$id);} my routes.php code isRoute::group(array('before' =>'auth'),function()
   {
 Route::get('/Gallery/delete',array('uses'=>'GalleryController@destroy','as'=>'destroy'));
  });

Comment: Check if $galleries is not null. Only if is an object of ForumGallery, try to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

You should check $galleries before delete it:

```
$galleries=ForumGallery::find($id);
if (!is_null($galleries)) {
    $galleries->delete();
}
```

Comment: sorry not working  when im clicking 1 delete  dispaly only this http://localhost/wys/wys/public/Gallery/delete/1

Comment: Are you sure that incoming ID is correct? Could you print id of $gallery? Also, you should add your redirect code after my example: return Redirect ::route('gallery',$id);

Comment: public function delete($id)
     {
       $id=Input::get('id');
            $newsevents= ForumGallery::find($id);
             if ($newsevents) 
             {
             $newsevents->delete();
             
            }
            return Redirect::route('gallery',$id);
     }controller.php still old error not working when im clicking id 6 delete dispaly only this localhost/wys/wys/public/Gallery/delete/6

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if a gallery has actually been found. Otherwise `find()` returns `null`:

```
$galleries = ForumGallery::find($id);
if ($galleries) {
    $galleries->delete();
}
```

Alternatively you can also use `findOrFail()` which will throw an Exception if no model is found and handle that exception globally (e.g. to display a 404 error)

```
$galleries = ForumGallery::findOrFail($id);
$galleries->delete();
```

### Edit

Judging from the comment you left on the other answer, you call the route by `/Gallery/delete/6`. If you want to do that you need to change your route:

```
Route::get('/Gallery/delete/{id}',array('uses'=>'GalleryController@destroy','as'=>'d‌​estroy'));
```

and controller method:

```
public function delete($id){
    $galleries=ForumGallery::findOrFail($id);
    $galleries->delete();
    return Redirect ::route('gallery',$id);
}
```

Comment: when im trying this code..$galleries = ForumGallery::find($id);
if ($galleries) {
    $galleries->delete();
}error was remove, but delete not done... im also do this code $galleries = ForumGallery::findOrFail($id);
$galleries->delete(); one error occur is lluminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ ModelNotFoundException

No query results for model [ForumGallery].  my model page  is class ForumGallery extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{

 use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;@var string
  
 protected $table = 'forum_galleries';
 * @var array

Comment: Then that means the `$id` was wrong or not set at all. How do you call the controller? like `/Gallery/delete?id=1`?

Comment: my route is Route::get('/Gallery/delete/',array('uses'=>'GalleryController@delete','as'=>'delete'));

Comment: Yes I know that, but how do you *call* it?

Comment: my blade.php
     <a href="{{URL::Route('delete',$gallery->id)}}">Delete</a><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" id="id" value="{{$gallery->id}}">

Comment: I know that too. But how do you **CALL** your route. It's probably either a link or a form.